# Finding source item in Workflow

Tags: development, workflow, visual-studio, content-approval, approval-process

I am new to Sharepoint and using Visual Studio 2008 I have created a workflow that uses custom content type based off workflow task list with additional columns for Approval Status and Approver Notes. 
Workflow is associated to list A, change or new item in this list creates a task in list B.
Can you tell me how, in my workflow, can I get a reference to an item in list A that started the workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an attached property `SPWorkflowActivationProperties WorkflowProperties`. You can get the source item via it's Item property:

```
SPListItem item = WorkflowProperties.Item;
```

Comment: just realised this during debugging... many thanks, marking as answered